# Guarantee on job duties for contracting work

Tags: france

I have searched about the subject but I couldn't find an answer, therefore I am asking here.

For an engineer who wants to work, sometimes it's possible to work at company A which then deploys the engineer to its client, company B.

However, the working contract is signed with company A, so details about the future work or client are not mentioned. These companies are known as SSII in France

Is there any way to modify the contract before signing in order not to be given work outside a certain field, or with some technologies?  Most of the time, oral statements are made, but they have no legal value.

Comment: Are you willing to be unemployed if these are the only openings that company A has?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I work in France in a "SSII" and I know many people who do.

I understand your concern, because most of the time, they hire you to work on a certain project, but once you're there, they give you another project that has nothing to do with what you asked for in the beginning.

Lots of my friends actually refused the project and asked them to find something else for them that might be more interesting. They might accept, but if they do not find something for you within weeks, they might break the contract with you.

Most of the time, people just accept what's given to them to gain exprience. But YOU CANNOT MODIFY THE CONTRACT YOURSELF.

I advice you to talk to them. Tell them you won't sign until it's mentionned on the contract that you're going to work on a specific field.

But even then, they might give you something that has nothing to do with what you want, as long as it's close enough to what it's written on the contract. For example, you might want to work in aeronautics, and they will give you a project of web developping just because the client works in aeronautics. So your demands must be very specific.

That's why generally, people avoid working with SSII, unless you're a junior and you want to gain experience, and you're desperate enough to work anywhere, it's better to work directly with the client.

Answer (score 2):

Effectively, contracts can say whatever two parties agree too.

If you have concerns about working within a certain field, or with certain technologies, you can raise them when discussing terms of the contract.

Note that you would need to have some bargaining power to make it happen. If there are two equivalent candidates, but one is less flexible than the other, they are going to go with the flexible candidate.